# Formatting inches in Excel (when coming from cm)

Tags: excel

I am trying to convert centimeters to inches.

**Step 1 = convert**

I use `=CONVERT(A1,"cm","in")`

**Step 2 = formatting**

So I read a lot of posts, where this solution comes very close. Format the cells as `# ?/?"''"`

This shows the values as in the image below, only ....

**Question:** See the 15 inches value on the right. I just cant make it outline to left and make it look like `15"` .... for the rest it works great. Only integer numbers dont look correctly formatted ...

Help appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 1):

hmmm, got it

Format cell as:     `# ##/#"''"`